# UnableError: unable to get cib

Tags: java, apache, high-availability, pacemaker

I'm trying to create cluster for Load balancer to forward my request to two apache instances by using Pace maker package. For that I installed "corosync, pcs, pacemaker" packages. 
I did the cluster setup for node1 and node2. Now when I'm trying to create cluster resource using the below command

```
sudo pcs resource create ClusterIP ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=<IP_ADDRESS> cidr_netmask=32 op monitor interval=30s
```

This command is giving below error.

```
Error: unable to get cib
```

So is there anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

You got that answer because your cluster hasn´t been created. You should use the following command to create one, for an example:

```
pcs cluster setup --start --name my_cluster z1.example.com z2.example.com
```

[Refer to this Website for further information:](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/high_availability_add-on_administration/s1-clusterconfigure-haaa)

Answer (score 0):

You might have stopped your cluster. That's why you are receiving this error. Start your cluster than trying creating a resource